# CVE-2016-4470 Patch information

Tags: c, security

Patch for CVE

[image]

**The description states :**

The `key_reject_and_link` function in `security/keys/key.c` in the Linux kernel through 4.6.3 does not ensure that a certain data structure is initialized, which allows local users to cause a denial of service (system crash) via vectors involving a crafted `keyctl` request2 command.

**Questions:**

1. Looking at the patch, how do the variables fix the bug?
2. Does it involve race condition? Explanation would be extremely helpful, as I am new in C
3. How exactly does this patch prevent a DOS condition

Answer (score 0):

1. Since the root cause of this CVE is that __key_link_begin fails, and variable edit is uninitialized, the method to fix this problem is to detect such failure of __key_link_begin. From my knowledge, link_ret is the return value of __key_link_begin(),
   the patch adds one condition (`link_ret == 0`) to verify whether __key_link_begin fails or not.
2. I think it should not involve race condition here. My guess is from  the stack trace shown in the [patch](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=38327424b40bcebe2de92d07312c89360ac9229a)
3. Please refer to the answer of Question 1.